# How do I delay a command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I tried:

```
/tp @e[type=ArmorStand,T=100] ~ ~1 ~
```

Then:

```
/tp @e[type=ArmorStand,Time=100] ~ ~1 ~
```

I'm stuck.

I am looking for a command-block only solution.

Comment: You can do something like a timer that starts from an output from a comparator or something like that. It depends on how long of a delay you need though. Actually, it kind of looks like you just want a slower clock, right? So I'd just use like a hopper clock rather than a repeat command

Comment: no it has to be with command blocks

Comment: What minecraft version are you running? If you are running 1.9 or above I can help you.

Comment: I posted a 1.9+ solution assuming you are using the latest version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you are trying to do `@e[T=100]` and `@e[Time=100]`, but `T` and `Time` are not selector arguments, so I will be showing you how to make a custom timer argument.

---

##This solution only works on Minecraft 1.9 and above!

This is possible with scoreboard objectives. You will have to do the following **for each command you want to delay**. Note that this also only works on commands executed on entities.

---

How to make:

1. Create a scoreboard objective to hold delays (I will use `time` as an example)

   ```
   /scoreboard objectives add time dummy
   ```
2. Create a command block arrangement like this:
   [image: Repeating > Chain > Conditional Chain]
3. Place the following commands into each command block:

- Repeat Command Block:

  ```
      /scoreboard players add @e[score_time_min=1] time 1
  ```
- Chain Command Block 1: Put your delayed command here. For example:

  ```
      /tp @e[type=ArmorStand,score_time_min={delay}] ~ ~1 ~
  ```
- Chain Command Block 2:

  ```
      /scoreboard players set @e[score_time_min={delay}] time 0
  ```

4. Start the delay by running this command:

   ```
   /scoreboard players set {entity} time 1
   ```

---

A few things to note:

- Replace `{delay}` with the delay you want in ticks, plus one. For example, if you want a delay of 5 seconds, you would put `101` there since `5sec * 20 tick/sec + 1 = 101`.
- Replace `{entity}` with the selector for the entity that you want to run the command. For example, `@e[type=ArmorStand,name=Bob]`.
- The command in the second command block is up to you to. Just know that your need to run the command with `{entity}` targeted and you must have `score_time_min={delay}` in the entity selector for that command.

---

If you want a full example, here are the commands for the command blocks to teleport an `ArmorStand` by the name of "Bob" 5 blocks in the air 5 seconds after running the start delay command (step #4 above):

```
/scoreboard players add @e[score_time_min=1] time 1
/tp @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Bob,score_time_min=101] ~ ~1 ~
/scoreboard players set @e[score_time_min=101] time 0
```

---

Feel free to comment on this post with any questions! Ill try to answer them as soon as possible!

For additional information on how to format target selectors and arguments, see the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors).

Comment: ah right, the whole "use a dummy command as a counter" trick. I forgot about that as a thing.

Comment: @Smart_Snake you are very welcome. If this answer helped you to solve your problem, remember to hit the checkmark towards the top of the post to signify that a solution has been found for the question.

Comment: hmm for some reason it will teleport if I put the command /scoreboard players set @e[type=ArmorStand] time 1 into the chat if I don't it won't work

Comment: That command is the command that triggers the delay. Therefore, running it is necessary. You can put it into a command block too.

Answer (score -3):

Depending on whether you want a delay of seconds, or a delay of minutes, you can just use a string of repeaters.

Comment: Just command blocks it's not like I'm making a MAP!

Answer (score -3):

If you need too many repeaters to do your delay, just /fill the area of repeaters you need. If it takes too much space, just deal with it.