# Minecraft Delayed Repeating Commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I play Minecraft 1.12.2 Java edition. I made a command block that basically shows a welcome intro (ex: Welcome to the world! Please ask  for creative mode.) I want it to repeat about every 30 seconds. I made a **HUGE** chain of redstone repeaters that takes up **A LOT** of space. It works, but I was wondering if there was any other easier way.

Comment: This was asked quite a few times before. I should actually clean up all those duplicates and bring them to one parent question, with proper answers. But I currently don't have time to go through all of them. I recommend you to for now look at https://www.google.com/search?q=minecraft+commands+delay+site%3Agaming.stackexchange.com and use one of the solutions that use increasing scoreboards or `/schedule`.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I delay a command](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274911/how-do-i-delay-a-command)

Comment: @Corsaka and all other close voters: Please at least check if the older question actually has a solution that works in the current version! I just checked all of the 11 questions of this type and none of them has an actually working answer. This is quite the mess. I'll make a new question with a proper, short question text, and clear and concise answer, then close all of these as duplicates of it.